# Display the checked row in another datatable when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

Display the checked row values in another table
Firstly i m trying to display the records in another table through Ajax..

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn').click(function() {
            var dataArr = [];
            $('input:checked').each(function() {
                alert($(this).closest('tr[id]').attr('id'));
                dataArr.push($(this).closest('tr[id]').attr('id')); 
            });
            // send data to back-end via ajax
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : 'Server.php/user',
                data : "content="+dataArr,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);// alert the data from the server
                },
                error : function() {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am sending multiple id in ajax.
 **My model is**

```
function get_row_details($jsonvalue) {
    $this->db->select("echo_id,echo_scan,price");
    $this->db->from('echo_investigation');
    $this->db->where_in('echo_id', $jsonvalue);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

In my Console I am getting the output as:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [echo_id] => 1
        [echo_scan] => Echo

        [price] => 1000
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [echo_id] => 2
        [echo_scan] => Fetal Echo
        [price] => 1500
    )

  )
```

But I don't know how to append in data table...Or else i have to use JavaScript to display the checked row in datatable....I am new to Ajax so Kindly Suggest me

Comment: If you are getting data in `success` function of AJAX call, then you have to write some jQuery to populate data in your HTML markup.

Comment: yeah but i am trying to access each value in alert but i am not getting that value

Comment: you were returning array of objects, best way to pass data to ajax call is to encode it in json, with `json_encode`.

Comment: Yeah now i got it..thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return Json From Model Instead Of Array

```
return json_encode($query->result());
```

after getting response show your data

```
    success: function(data) {
             var obj = JSON.parse(data);
             for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
              console.log("Echo_ID : "+obj[i].echo_id);
              console.log("Echo Scan: "+obj[i].echo_scan); 
              console.log("Price: "+obj[i].price);                     
                    //do your stuff here
                }
          });
    },
```

Comment: Thankyou i got the output......now i will try for displaying in table...you saved my time.